# CefSharp.BrowserSubProcess.Core WCF pipe failure

Tags: wcf, cefsharp

Our application is using CefSharp version 73.1.130. The issue only occurs on a small number of internal workstations within our organization. Worth noting, we are also seeing the same error with CefSharp version 92. Another strange thing is that it the issue is consistent, but only when the web apps are launched through certain navigations. Other navigations work consistently for these users.

We use [RegisterJsObject](https://cefsharp.github.io/api/73.1.x/html/M_CefSharp_WebBrowserExtensions_RegisterJsObject.htm) to register a javascript object with browser. If I understand correctly, asynchronous binding is preferred moving forward.

The issue presents as strange/unexpected behavior in the hosted web application due to failure to retrieve context from the host WinForms application. The behavior would suggest a failure to register/bind the js object with the RegisterJsObject method. However, that method is not throwing an exception.

Enabled Cef logging showed the following error:

`ERROR:JavascriptRootObjectWrapper.cpp(34)] IBrowserProcess is null, unable to bind object`

After looking into the code, it appears the location that the value pointed to by "IBrowserProcess" is set is in WcfEnabledSubProcess::OnBrowserCreated (https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/73/CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.Core/WcfEnabledSubProcess.cpp). I was able to build CefSharp and add additional logging to that method.

On my workstation (I'm not affected by the issue), I get through OnBrowserCreated with no exceptions. However, on my coworkers workstation I see the following line is failing:

```
...
            channelFactory->Open();

            auto browserProcess = channelFactory->CreateChannel();
            auto clientChannel = ((IClientChannel^)browserProcess);

            try
            {
                clientChannel->Open();   <-- FAILS

                browser->ChannelFactory = channelFactory;
                browser->BrowserProcess = browserProcess;
            }
            catch (Exception^)
            {
            }
        }
```

With the error:

`There was an error reading from the pipe: The pipe has been ended. (109, 0x6d)`

Has anyone seen this issue before? I'm not sure how much this will help, but does anyone know if it's possible to enable WCF tracing with the CefSharp.BrowserSubProcess.exe. I have been trying this, but no luck so far.

Comment: Possibly similar to https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/915 for testing purposes try run as administrator on the problem workstation.

Comment: @amaitland Thanks! Going to try that out. Worth noting: after switching to async Javascript binding for testing purposes, my co-worker is no longer having the issue. Ideally we're hoping to identity the workstation issue and fix that, but we may end up needing to migrate to aync jsb instead of sync.